# How to open a bootstrap 5 modal which is in child from a button click which is in parent , without installing ng bootstrap in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a button in parent component, upon clicking it I want to open a modal which is in child component. I am using bootstrap 5 in my project. I don't want to install ngx-bootstrap due to some restrictions.

It is working when I add data-bs-target and data-bs-toggle attribute to the button and have `<child></child>` 
instance in parent component. But, before opening the module I need to do some validations.

How can I implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

futhermore to install bootstrap, install @types/bootstrap

```
npm install --save @types/bootstrap
```

Then you can control a Modal using typeScript. E.g.

```
  <!--in the button I use template reference-->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="show(modal)">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
<!--see the template reference-->
<div #modal class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in .ts

```
  import {Modal} from 'bootstrap' //<--import Modal

  show(modalElement){
    const modal=new Modal(modalElement);
    modal.show();
  }
```

Or using ViewChild

```
  @ViewChild('modal') modalRef
  show(){
    //see that using ViewChildren you use nativeElement
    const modal=new Modal(this.modalRef.nativeElement);
    modal.show();
  }
```

As your child is who has the modal, use a template reference variable in children (e.g. `#modal`) so you parent can be

```
  <button type="button" (click)="show(child.modal)">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <child #child></child>

  //in this case we need use "nativElement"
  show(modalRef){
    const modal=new Modal(modalRef.nativeElement);
    modal.show();
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eich3l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi, I added the template ref variable to child template (#modal), but in ```show(child.modal)```, I am getting an error ```Property modal does not exist on type ModalComponent```. And also what is the type of ```modalRef``` the parameter in the ```show(modalRef)```

Comment: After typing ```child.``` and press ctrl+space, I can see ```modal``` in the list of properties, but error still persists.

Comment: child.modal should be a `ElementRef` is you use `ViewChild` and `HTMLDivElement` if you pass directly the template reference to open a modal parent in parent -I just update the stackblitz-. About error "Property modal does not exist" I don't know what happens, you can try using `show(child['modal'])` but is strange, In Angular all the variables are public by defect -and a template reference is the same type of the "div". Has you a directive in your modal?.NOTE: You always can pass the "child" and in show use `child.modal.nativeElement` to create the bootstrap modal

Comment: Thanks, I will try these and get back to you.

Comment: Hey, It worked with passing the child through the ```show(child)``` and using ```child.modal.nativeElement```.  ```@ViewChild('modal') modal:ElementRef``` here it was asking me to initialize the ```modal``` property, I had to do ```modal!```. Thanks a lot.