# Failed to open Modal: angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to work with modal  in angular but i failed to do it, this is my code ts :

```
public onOpenModal(caregiver: Caregiver, mode: string): void {
    const container = document.getElementById('main-container');
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.style.display = 'none';
    button.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
    if (mode === 'add') {
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#addEmployeeModal');
    }
    if (mode === 'edit') {
      this.editEmployee = caregiver;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#updateEmployeeModal');
    }
    if (mode === 'delete') {
      this.deleteEmployee = caregiver;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#deleteEmployeeModal');
    }
    container.appendChild(button);
    button.click();
  }
```

this is my HTML :

```
<a   class="btn btn-primary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit" (click)="onOpenModal(caregiver, 'edit')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>
                        <a   class="btn btn-secondary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"  (click)="onOpenModal(caregiver, 'delete')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

please can't find solution to this, i don't have any error, but nothing is working ! please any suggestion.

Comment: You are not using Angular as recommended i would say.  we should not dealing with create elements etc.  and for modal why don't you try to use any library like angular material or vmware clarity or any other angular library and use the modal

Comment: are you using Bootstrap 5?, take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306188/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-5-modal-which-is-in-child-from-a-button-click-which-is-i/68306753#68306753

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows, hope it might solve your issue:

**Parent Component**

Import `MatDialog`:

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Inject `MatDialog` Dependency:

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }
```

Call `onOpenModal()` from Parent component:

```
onOpenModal(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(addEmployeeModalComponent, {
      width: ...,
      height: ...,
      data: ...
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
       ...
    });
  }
```

**Modal Component**

Import `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` & `MatDialogRef`:

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Inject `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` & `MatDialogRef` Dependencies:

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<addEmployeeModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any)
```

//Use `dialogRef` and `data` variable as per your need

Comment: I'm not using angular material

Comment: You could use angular material whatsoever :)