# Angular 13 with Bootstrap 5: How to open a modal programmatically

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am using Angular 13 and have included Bootstrap 5 in my project by linking to the CDN links like shown here: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#css 
and here: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#bundle

Everything works fine as far as components are concerned, but I cannot find a way to open a modal programmatically. I don't won't to hide the modal using `display: none/block`, because this method doesn't include the animations that come with the component (like dropping from the top of the screen etc).

The component works fine if I use the button that triggers the behaviour, just like here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#live-demo

For now, my solution is to keep this button with `display: none` and trigger a manual click in my code, but this seems hacky to me.

Is there a way to achieve this without using ng-bootstrap?

EDIT:

Eliseo's comment seems to be in the right direction, by running npm install @types/bootstrap, vscode recognizes Modal from 'bootstrap'. However, running ng serve, gives me this error

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap' in ...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306188/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-5-modal-which-is-in-child-from-a-button-click-which-is-i/68306753#68306753 ?

Comment: @Eliseo This seems to be towards the right direction. However, after installing @types/bootstrap, vs code autocompletes Modal etc, but when running ng serve I get: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap'

Comment: Looks like I needed to have bootstrap@5 installed as well

Comment: It looks like installing bootstrap@5 starts messing with some components. For example, my navbar expands but doesn't collapse anymore. @Eliseo any ideas?

Comment: The error you posted indicates to me that you'll need to have the `node_modules/bootstrap` installed in your production environment, and will have to run your app through `ng serve`, and will require NodeJS to be installed on your server anyway... Sure you'll be able to do so? You won't be able to simply host some html, css and javascript!

Answer (score 0):

Using by **ElementRef** you can do this check this out.

```
<button #open type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Launch static backdrop modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade"   id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button #close  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('open',{read: ElementRef})closeRef!:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('close',{read: ElementRef})modelRef!:ElementRef;
 
 
 ngOnInit(): void {
     
   setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('hua');
    
     this.closeRef.nativeElement.click()
   }, 100);
   setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('hua');
    
   
    this.modelRef.nativeElement.click()
   }, 10000);
 }
}
```

Comment: This is using the same hacky way as I did, it just selects the button element with view child instead of document.getElementById.