# Bootstrap 5 modal not working with Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I am currently trying to add a modal to my angular project. i have tried copying the example in the boot strap docs and have watched through videos stating that you have to change the data-toggle to data-bs-target etc and it still doesnt seem to work.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                        data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                        Launch demo modal
                    </button>

                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-danger mt-5" (click)="deleteContact(contact.id) ">Delete</button> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="activityForm" *ngIf="contact.id">
                <app-activities [childItem]="contact"></app-activities>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306188/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-5-modal-which-is-in-child-from-a-button-click-which-is-i/68306753#68306753

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work".

Comment: The modal simply doesnt open when you click the button for it to open.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out my problem and it was simply due to the fact that i hadn't specified a path for my scripts section in angular.json file.

so in the angular.json file you have to scroll down to the the scripts section and including the following path:

"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"